# How Can i Set parent View from sub view Only use programmatically not use StoryBoard Dragging?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit

i try to set parent view that in Storyboard i already set height it. but i need to change it when i touch on blue button but view that i add class not update constrain and view frame or maybe it change constrain but not update .  Can i update it ?

[image: i set code here but it not update]

[image: black is View is not updated]

[image: this is constrains i add to button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to update a constraint which was set in the Interface Builder. To accomplish this, drag the already set height anchor to your ViewController. It will look something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourViewHeightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Than in your update function just do:

```
func setupHeight() {
     yourViewHeightAnchor.constant = 100 // Set your value here 
     yourView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: Ty i try this  it work but Can i update it from subview not parent' view ? and not use IBOutlet ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "update from subview" ?

Comment: i mean  if i have Parent View then i add subview  to parent in side of subview i have button that i can click it and resize parent view. Can i do that ?(without using anything from storyboard)

Comment: Yes. If you are doing it without storyboard, and when you are creating the constraint, just store it in a local variable. For instance: let heightAcnhor =  yourView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)